# How to set upstart as default on Debian?

Tags: debian, upstart, sysvinit

I have a virtual server running Debian. For some reason it doesn't boot if I am using sysvinit. I assume the problem lies with the host operating system, since it's a Virtuozzo based machine and not fully virtual. 
It does boot when using upstart though.
The problem is that I am also using cron-apt which reinstalls sysvinit every time an update arrives. 
Is there any way to tell Debian to use upstart as default? Or to lock it in place using apt?

**Update**:

I tried the solution suggested below and it seems to work. The correct syntax for the apt preferences is this:

```
Package: sysvinit
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Comment: What version of Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the existing question  [Upstart on Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/upstart-on-debian.k)

Regardless of version, it must be disclaimed that running `upstart` as the init system in Debian seems to be "at your own risk". That being said...

In **Debian Wheezy** (oldstable as of 2015), the [`sysvinit`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/sysvinit) package is marked `Essential`, which is probably why the [`upstart`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/upstart) isn't very "sticky".

Two mechanisms that can be used to place restrictions on `apt`'s behavior are [`apt_preferences`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/apt_preferences) and dpkg blacklisting. `apt_preferences` are described in files under `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`; read the man page linked above.

dpkg blacklisting is described in a [nixCraft blog post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-apt-get-blacklisting-packages-using-hold-option/). You could try:

```
echo "sysvinit hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

As of **Debian Jessie** (stable as of 2015), the [`sysvinit`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/sysvinit) package is a transitional package and no longer essential:

> This package depends on init, which is an essential package that pulls
>   in the default init system. Starting with jessie, this will be systemd
>   on Linux. It facilitates a smooth transition and provides a fallback
>   SysV init binary which can be used to boot the system via the
>   init=/lib/sysvinit/init kernel command line parameter in case the
>   system fails to start after the switch to systemd.
>
> If your system successfully boots with systemd or if you have chosen
>   to stick with sysvinit-core, this package can be removed safely.

So I would guess that you aren't running Jessie, but if you are you could try the Wheezy solutions described above.

Comment: Year, I am currently running Wheezy. Haven't upgraded yet.

Comment: I was trying out your apt_preferences suggestion. However I don't get the man page... I see settings to change priorities. But how would I make upstart "sticky"?

Comment: I would try setting the `priority` for upstart very high (> 1000) and the priority for `sysvinit` very low (negative)

Comment: I found out that you also need to use the `Pin: origin=""`, because apt-preferences is usually for pinning where the packages come from. The empty string allows you to just pin any package despite of its origin.

Comment: This answer is now out of date. Upstart has actually been removed from Debian as of version 9.