# After cloning Fedora 14 install to another machine, onboard NIC is seen as eth1 instead of eth0. Why?

Tags: fedora, networking, migration

I have the following procedure for replicating a Fedora workstation setup.

1. Boot from a Live CD, make tgz's of the filesystems.
2. Go to new machine, make filesystems, dump the tgz's in the proper places.
3. Adjust UUID's in /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/menu.lst
4. Run grub-install
5. Reboot!

The nice thing is that DHCP assigns the new machine an unique name, and users have /home mounted on the server. Graphics configuration aren't a worry either, since recent versions of Xorg are wicked smart in auto-detecting graphic adapters.

So everything works like a snap... with the exception of one small quirk:

In the first boot of the new machine, network startup fails. It turns out the machine thinks there's no such thing as an eth0, but there *is* an eth1 and it is the machine's onboard ethernet. So I have to go to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts, rename ifcfg-eth0 to ifcfg-eth1, and edit the DEVICE= line in it. *Then* I reboot and everything works.

I believe somewhere, in some file, there is information associating eth0 with the MAC of the "Master Mold" machine's eth0. But where?

P.S.: I don't use NetworkManager.

Comment: This is not really relevant to your question, but I recommend partimage over the approach you used to copy/replicate filesystems.

Comment: I suggest changing your title. It doesn't really reflect your question accurately.

Comment: If your list of changes is exhaustive and you have an ssh server, you missed generating a new ssh host key. See also [Moving linux install to a new computer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/moving-linux-install-to-a-new-computer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my machine it is

/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

This is a Debian squeeze machine, but it is probably similar for other Linux distributions. Mine looks like

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, probably run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single line.
# MAC addresses must be written in lowercase.

# Firewire device 00e081000026d042 (ohci1394)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:e0:81:00:00:26:d0:42", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10de:0x0057 (forcedeth)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:e0:81:70:18:22", NAME="eth1"
```

Tip: doing

```
/etc# grep -r eth0 * | less
```

will give you the answer in a couple of minutes, probably. That is what I did.