# Does Grub2 support putting /boot on a RAID5 partition?

Tags: grub2, software-raid

It looks like *currently* most OS installers insist on putting /boot on a non-RAID partition (or the kind of RAID1 partition that "looks like" a non-RAID partition), even the installers that support RAID5 and GRUB2.

I'm guessing this limitation is a historical relic leftover from Grub1.
My understanding is that Grub1 doesn't know anything about RAID and so can't boot off any kind of RAID array -- except for RAID arrays that "look like" a non-RAID array.

Is this a limitation of Grub2, or of the OS installers?

I've heard [rumors](http://fossplanet.com/f13/release-criteria-proposal-support-boot-raid-205501/) that Grub2 is "able to support /boot on
RAID-0, RAID-1 or RAID-5, metadata 0.90, 1.0, 1.1 or 1.2".

Does Grub2 really support putting /boot on a software RAID1 partition with 1.2 metadata?

Does Grub2 really support putting /boot on a software RAID5 partition?

An ideal answer would link to a tutorial that explains how to move a /boot partition (on a non-RAID partition) to a RAID5 partition.

By "looks like" a non-RAID partition, I mean either

- when Grub1 reads only one hard drive of a software RAID1 array with a ext3 or ext4 filesystem and ignores the RAID metadata 0.90 or 1.0 at the end of the partition, it looks just like the a non-RAID ext2 file system that Grub1 can handle.
  Or
- Not a software or fake-RAID, but a full hardware raid that looks like a normal non-RAID disk.

Comment: Data points: in Ubuntu 10.04, Grub2 supports some RAID arrangements but not the mdraid modes with the metadata at the beginning. In Ubuntu 11.10, Grub2 supports all mdraid modes.

Comment: @Gilles: Backporting later versions of Grub2 should not be a problem. It has basically no dependencies.

Comment: [My answer to an earlier unix.sx question - "Copying linux install from non-RAID/x86 to RAID/x86-64"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22099/4671) seems relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes grub2 is fully raid ( and LVM ) aware.  In fact you do not need a separate /boot partition at all; you can just put everything on the raid5.

Ideally you want to not install with a /boot partition at all, but removing it after the fact simply means copying all of the files to the root partition, and reinstalling grub, like this:

```
umount /boot
mount /dev/[bootpart] /mnt
cp -ax /mnt/* /boot
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Of course you then need to remove the /boot line from /etc/fstab, and you still have the partition laying around, just unused.

Note you can also grub-install to all of the drives in the raid5 so that you can boot from any of them.  The Ubuntu grub-pc package will prompt you ( `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` to get it to ask again ) to check off all of the drives you want it installed on and install it for you.

Comment: So I don't have to use metadata=0.9?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, no, nor should you.

Comment: what if one disk fails?
The raid needs a working operating system to rebuild and grub needs a working raid to boot.. there is a deadlock then.
Creating and mirroring a boot partition would be better, right?

Comment: @cIph3r, no: while grub can't rebuild the degraded array it can still boot from it just fine.

Comment: nice, and when installing grub the system asks to write grub to the mbr,
what to do then, install on (say /dev/sda) and dd the mbr it to the other 3?

Comment: @cIph3r, no, you just choose to install grub to all three drives.

Comment: @psusi Manually? The installation procedure just asks for one!

Comment: @Enzo, yes manually.  You just run grub-install once on each drive.  Or if you are running a debian based distro, use `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` and you can select multiple drives for it to be installed to ( and automatically reinstalled to when upgrading ).

Comment: I have successfully done what you said. I have installed ubuntu server on a RAID 5 with 3 drives with one entry point "/" . Then, I removed one drive, I rebooted and it worked. Then I added a new drive to the RAID array, I did a grub-install /dev/sdx and it booted from that particular drive again.

Comment: Historically, Grub used to be only able to read part of RAID, I remember having to put the /boot partition on a RAID 1 (mirrored). Now Grub2 can real all MDRAIDs (the standard Linux software raid, which is super stable and very very good and best of all: Hardware independent, so it will boot on any system that you hook up the drives, no hardware controller necessary)

Answer (score 0):

This is a frightful mess in linux. The default superblock version using mdadm is version 1.20. Once you go above 0.90 for booting you are in uncharted territory. Certainly lilo shows no interest above 1.0. Your best bet is to form the raid arrays (tip: use the parameter --metadata=0.90 in your mdadm create) before you use the installation procedure. Then you can install on the RAID array and use your favourite bootloader.

Comment: You can not use LILO to boot from a raid5 no matter what metadata format you use.

Comment: LILO has been deprecated MANY MANY years ago, it should not be used anymore, GRUB1 and GRUB2 replaced it.