# How to clone linux installation onto an external harddisk?

Tags: backup, dd, cloning, external-hdd

I see a lot of `dd` related questions, but could not find answers to the following. If question/answers already exist, please point to them, then flag to close, delete or merge.

1. Can a working linux installation (say on `/dev/sda7`)  be cloned to an external hard disk partition (say `/dev/sdb2`), while on it? (`/dev/sdb` is a 1TB USB hard disk, `/dev/sdb2` is of size 100GB)
2. If not, can I do it using a live cd? Will the cloned partition on external drive be bootable?
3. If it is not bootable, how to do that?

**Why want to do that ?** : Need to carry the cloned external drive than the laptop itself, with all the installed (& customized) programs and data.

Additional info (relevant parts only):

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        2550    20482843+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda7            5660        6904    10000431   83  Linux

$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7             9.4G  7.4G  1.6G  83% /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone a mounted filesystem, but it's a bad idea because you'll be copying the filesystem in an inconsistent state. There's a real risk of losing data.

There are ways to clone a mounted filesystem, but they require preparation beforehand. For example, if the filesystem is on a block device that permits mirroring (such as LVM volumes or md-raid RAID1 volumes), you can create a mirror, then sever its link with the original. LVM also allows the creation of snapshots: an image of a filesystem, frozen in time, which can be safely read (cloning at the block device level is a bit iffier but possible in some cases).

So to answer your question: 1. no. 2. yes; yes but not automatically. 3. You need to install a bootloader on the external disk.

Since you'll need to reboot anyway, I recommend booting under a specialized tool for disk backups and maintenance, such as [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) or [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Can you add how to install bootloader (esp. if using GParted or Clonezilla Live)?

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham It depends on your bootloader. The easiest thing is to chroot into the backup and run the bootloader installation program from there (e.g. for Grub: `update-grub; grub-install /dev/something`). By the way, are you making a backup, or an installation that can be used independently? If the latter, you should change a few things that should be globally unique. See [Moving linux install to a new computer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2865) and [How can I most easily migrate all my apps and settings from one Ubuntu install to another?](http://askubuntu.com/a/5025)

Comment: Thanks, those links are much useful. I am trying to clone the installation, to be used independently. That's why I removed the `/backup` and `/partition` tags. (But it is added again :( )

Answer (score 2):

DD is a wonderful utility for doing any of the tasks, but it is (potentially)problematic; mix up source and destination discs, you are screwed. There is a 'distribution' based on Debian that does everything you want using DD under the hood. It is clonezilla which can be downloaded from http://clonezilla.org/. I have used it on many different machines without a hitch. It will also copy the MBR so the disc could be booted.

Alan

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is compress whole fs with `partimage` and restore it on the other computer.