# How to get the cloned guest connected to the Internet?

Tags: networking, rhel, virtual-machine, kvm

I made a clone of a VM(running a version of Centos 6) on KVM, but the clone wouldn't connect to the Internet. Issuing `ifconfig` shows no interfaces but the `lo`. Interestingly, the original system can connect to the Internet. I didn't make any change to the default settings. Anything that I could do to make it work?

Comment: How did you clone the VM. `virt-clone`. type `ifconfig -a` inside the VM and post the result

Comment: @xczzhh Consider posting an answer to your own question so it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a Linux installation, you need to change a few things that should be unique (see some tips in [Moving linux install to a new computer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/moving-linux-install-to-a-new-computer)). In particular, your cloned virtual machine probably has the same address as the original, and this means that you can't connect them both to the same network at the same time.

Make sure that the clone has a distinct MAC address. The MAC address is probably assigned by the virtual machine software (here KVM).

Make sure that the clone has a distinct IP address. The IP address may be configured statically in the guest OS, or may be obtained over DHCP. In the case of DHCP, if the IP address is assigned dynamically, you don't need to do anything special; if it's assigned based on the MAC address, making the MAC unique is sufficient (you need to do that anyway); if it's based on the name, give the clone a unique name.