# Transfer a Fedora system to another computer

Tags: linux, fedora, lvm, grub, cloning

I'd like to transfer my Fedora to a remote machine. Fedora is under Grub 2.0 and on the remote machine there is a Centos system and Grub 0.97. In fact, I have two questions.

First is how to properly add an entry to the hosting grub. The second one is how to copy Fedora filesystem to the machine on which Centos is running. Fedora's `lsblk` output is:

```
sda                      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1                   8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                   8:2    0 231.8G  0 part 
  ├─fedora-usr (dm-0)  253:0    0  14.7G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─fedora-swap (dm-1) 253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─fedora-root (dm-2) 253:2    0  30.5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─fedora-tmp (dm-3)  253:3    0     4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─fedora-home (dm-4) 253:4    0 178.7G  0 lvm  /home
```

How could I add this structure to the remote machine while keeping the existing Centos partition schema?

```
├─sda1                         8:1    0    25G  0 part 
├─sda2                         8:2    0 279.5G  0 part 
├─sda3                         8:3    0 198.9G  0 part 
├─sda4                         8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5                         8:5    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda6                         8:6    0 194.8G  0 part 
  ├─vg_centos-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg_centos-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0   3.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vg_centos-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0   141G  0 lvm  /home
```

Can I add `/dev/sda7` and so on?

UPD#1 the both systems aren't RAID disk the both have lvm disks and the master boot is MBR not GPT

Comment: Are you asking how would make the Fedora system part of the CentOS system so that you could dual boot them on the CentOS system?

Comment: Yes, this is my case, i would like a boot option

Comment: if the business is to complex may be a virtualization is a good solution?

Comment: Absolutely, I didn't want to confuse the Q&A here but I would definitely go that route. There are various ways to take a system and convert it fairly easily to a virtual machine. It's typically called P2V or physical to virtual. But that's a different question 8-). I've done this many times over the years, it's fairly painless once you understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If there is enough space left on your disk, you can add a new partition to your remote machine's disk. A tool like `gparted` for example will allow you to resize existing partitions to free the space you need. You don't need to create another `/boot` partition. You can merge the one on your computer and the one on your remote machine. It will be a lot easier to configure `grub` this way.

Is your Fedora system heavily customised? If I were you, I wouldn't copy the entire system, but only the `/home` partition and I would reinstall a system on the new host. It can be very tricky to copy a system which hadn't been designed for (like a virtual machine can be for example). For example, you'd have to review entirely your `/etc/fstab`, make sure all the firmwares you need are available for your new material...

If you know what you're doing, you'll have to recreate the LVM schema and then copy your data.

Comment: Good idea do not copy system entirely but probe a new fedora install,  i should try it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're ultimately after by doing this but I would probably recommend not attempting to do this. Moving a system from one set of hardware to another can be problematic and is usually a task reserved for the most skilled in dealing with Linux.

#### Hardware differences

For starters you have to make sure that both systems have the same type of hardware architecture.

- Are they both Intel sytems? AMD systems?
- Are they 32-bit or 64-bit systems?
- Graphics cards the same?
- Networking and other hardware?

Re-configuring this hardware can be problematic *after* a system has been installed.

#### Disk partitioning differences

Disk layouts can be even trickier to replicate from one system to the next. There are several technologies that you have to be familiar with.

- Is the drive formatted using MBR (Master Boot Record) vs. GPT (GUID Partitioning Table)?
- Do the drives contain a software RAID (mdadm)?
- Do they contain a LVM (logical volume management) layer?

In general I would recommend collecting the files from the /etc and /home directories, doing a re-installation of the OS on the actual hardware you're interested in moving it to, and re-applying the configurations post-installation.

Comment: Moving or cloning a Linux installation to another machine isn't very difficult. See e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/moving-linux-install-to-a-new-computer

Comment: @Gilles, I've done the same myself in lift a OS from one physical box to another. This question is slightly different in the sense that for one, he's trying to mash an existing system into another and make it a dual boot, and two, he's trying to replicate the HDD topology of the Fedora system into the CentOS system. To do this would require expertise in several disk utilities that most people just aren't going to be able to deal with. Just my $0.02.