# Which config files in /etc folder must be unique for each computer?

Tags: configuration, backup, rsync, etc, restore

I am doing a restoration test of backup files on a computer. Without putting much thought into it, I did an `rsync` to replace all files in `/etc` folder with the ones in the backup. Then, I realize I shouldn't really be doing it as the passwords and user names for the two computers are not the same.

After a reboot, the computer is in a state where it cannot start, and I would possibly have to reinstall it from scratch. Now my question is, given the same OS, what are the files in `/etc` folder that are unique for each computer. This would allow me to fine-tune `rsync` to exclude those files in the future when doing a restoration from backup.

Comment: You might want to boot into rescue mode and fix `/etc/fstab`. That's probably the main thing that's stopping you from booting up.

Comment: But this idea of rsync'ing the whole `/etc` tree is bad to begin with. This sort of thing is why backup systems have automated de-duped logic. Definitionally anything under `/etc` can vary from system to system.

Comment: @JoelDavis, thanks for pointing out that my approach is not correct. This is the first time I am doing it. Does it mean that I have to go through all config files one by one? I am hoping for a less tedious approach.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just rsync the `/etc` on each node and just use `tar cjpf` server side? That wouldn't use much additional space since most of the files are text. That's better than picking through each node's `/etc` looking for files that are different.

Comment: Either that or use an enterprise backup system that will take care of de-dupe for you and you can just backup the entire system and not worry about it.

Comment: @JoelDavis, for backup itself, I am using `duplicity`. I just want to test the backup by restoring it on another computer.

Comment: If you're doing a bare metal restore to the other computer, you should be able to get away with just making sure the filesystems look identical. Usually BRE's boot to a temporary environment, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are very few files that absolutely must be different between two machines, and need to be regenerated when [cloning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/moving-linux-install-to-a-new-computer/2868#2868):

- The host name `/etc/hostname`.
- The SSH host keys: `/etc/ssh_host_*_key*` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key*` or similar location.
- The random seed: `/var/lib/urandom/random-seed` or `/var/lib/random-seed` or similar location. (`/var/lib/systemd/random-seed` on systems using systemd)

Anything else could be identical if you have a bunch of identical machines.

A few files are typically different on machines with different hardware:

- `/etc/fstab`, `/etc/crypttab`, `/etc/mdadm.conf`, and bootloader configuration files (if located in `/etc` — some distributions put them in `/boot`) if disks are partitioned differently.
- `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, if present, if the machines have different graphics cards.
- Modules to load or blacklist in `/etc/modules`, `/etc/modprobe.conf`, `/etc/modprobe.d/` and `/etc/modutils/`.

In addition, some network configuration may need to change, in particular:

- If you have static IP addresses, they need to be diversified per machine. The location of IP configuration varies between distribution (e.g. `/etc/network/interfaces` on Debian, `/etc/sysconfig/network` on Red Hat).
- `/etc/hosts` often contains the host name.
- Mail configuration often contains the host name: check `/etc/mailname`.

There's no general answer to “what are the files in `/etc` folder (…) are unique for each computer” because the whole purpose of `/etc` is to store files that can be customized on each computer. For example, if you have different accounts on different machines, then obviously you can't share the account database — and if you want to be able to share the account database, then you'll end up with the same accounts.

Generally speaking, don't try to share `/etc` by default unless you have a set of machines with the same software configuration — same installed software, same accounts, etc. If you do share `/etc`, you'll need to blacklist a few files from sharing as indicated above.

If you have machines with different configurations, then whitelist what you synchronize. Treat files in `/etc` as distinct on different machines, like files in `/var`. Synchronize only the ones that you've decided should apply everywhere.

One possible way to manage synchronization is to keep machine-specific files in a different directory, e.g. `/local/etc`, and make symbolic links like `/etc/fstab -> ../local/etc/fstab`. This still requires a largely homogeneous set of machines in terms of software as different distributions put files in different locations. Or, conversely, keep only the machine-specific files in `/etc` and all generic files elsewhere — but typical distributions don't accommodate this well.

You obviously can't do a live test of the restoration of the system configuration of one system on a different system. To test the restoration of your backups, fire up a virtual machine that emulates the hardware configuration sufficiently well (in particular, with a similar disk layout).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. This is exactly what I need to know.