# Cinnamon running without video hardware acceleration after moving HD to a new PC

Tags: linux, drivers, cinnamon, display, display-settings

I have just upgraded my PC. It was an old intel Q8400 with an nvidia graphics card. I changed the CPU (now an i3-6300) + Motherboard, and ditched the graphics card (want to use intel's graphics card that comes with the CPU).

Now, however, I get the message that Cinnamon is running without video hardware acceleration, and everything on screen is "laggy". I also have a dual monitor setup and when I go to system settings -> display I only see one display named as "laptop". Display detection does not work, and they are mirrored. Logically it has to do with the drivers.

Based on [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/moving-linux-install-to-a-new-computer) I should look for a related xorg.conf file, but there seems to be none related (below are my xorg.conf file search results)

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-quirks.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-trackpoint.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vmmouse.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf
/usr/share/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/xorg.conf.d.5.gz
```

System info based on `inxi` (seems like Intel drivers are actually being used):

```
$ inxi -b

System:    Host: HomePC Kernel: 3.16.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Cinnamon 2.6.13  Distro: Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
Machine:   Mobo: ASUSTeK model: B150M-C version: Rev X.0x serial: 151055956202383
           Bios: American Megatrends version: 0402 date: 09/25/2015 
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-6300 CPU (-HT-MCP-) clocked at 760.00 MHz  
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 1912 
           X.org: 1.15.1 drivers: fbdev,intel (unloaded: vesa) tty size: 80x24 Advanced Data: N/A for root  
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: r8169  
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 256.1GB (6.7% used) 
Info:      Processes: 215 Uptime: 1 min Memory: 1472.4/15928.1MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 1.9.17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very old and no longer relevant (for me at least), so I am going to close it. For the record, I ditched cinnamon for gnome at the time. Unfortunately I cannot tell if any of the answers will work. Thank you for commenting though!

Comment: You shouldn't close the question, as it may be useful to someone else who has the same issue. Also, you can't really close a question yourself... do you mean that you are going to self-delete it?

Comment: @Greenonline actually meant I will accept my own answer, seemed the same like closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with my own machine when I installed an NVidia driver but couldn't get it to work with cinnamon.  I had to use my old intel drivers for cinnamon.  The xorg.conf file automatically defaulted to the NVidia driver, so I had to manually change the driver, but then I got this hardware acceleration issue.

The fix I performed for this issue was:
in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, delete the line that says `Option "AccelMethod" "None"`.

Answer (score 1):

I had that same problem when I got the newest generation of Core i5 CPU and use the integrated Intel graphics.

Debian stable doesn't have the latest versions of the Linux kernel or of Mesa, both of which need to be a minimum version or newer for each generation of intel graphics.

The Debian 11 will run the graphics in a 10th gen core ix CPU, but not an 11th gen.  At some point before Debian 11 was released as stable, Linux Mint caught up with 10th gen Intel support, but not on Debian until Debian 11 was stable.

Only Debian-based distro I've found that (at the time I'm posting this) supports 11th Gen Intel Core graphics yet is the AHS (Advanced Hardware Support) version of MX.

Arch and presumably other rolling release distros should run it just fine.