# How can I move a single partition to another empty drive?

Tags: partition, dd, move-partition

I've got a partition P1 (which contains my Linux OS) on a drive A.

I've just gotten a completely new drive B (that is larger than partition P1 AND the entire drive A).

I'd like to copy across the partition from drive A to drive B, and possible resize it later on.

Can this be done with `dd`? I could easily create a new parition table on drive B, and just `cp` the files across - but this seems like it might be slightly slower due to the filesystem overhead.

---

```
Output of `parted --list`:
```

It would be the partition 4 that I want to copy to another drive.

```
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB               BIOS boot partition   bios_grub
 2      1049kB  1074MB  1073MB  fat32        EFI System            boot, esp
 3      1075MB  183GB   181GB   ext4         Linux filesystem
 4      183GB   250GB   67.5GB  ext4         Basic data partition
```

Please ignore any reference to the boot drive / functionality (which I'll worry about later on) - keeps this question concise.

Comment: See also this question: [Moving Linux install to a new computer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/moving-linux-install-to-a-new-computer/724900)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes ,that's what `dd` is for.  Assuming:

- `sxb` is the drive to copy from
- `sxc` is the drive to copy to
- `sxb4` is the fourth partition on the second drive that you want to copy from
- `sxc1` is the partition you've created to be of equal size to `sxb4`

do :

```
    parted /dev/sxc
    GNU Parted 3.2
    Using /dev/sxc
    Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
    (parted) mklabel GPT
    Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sxc will be destroyed and all data on this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?
    Yes/No? Yes
    (parted) mkpart primary 0.0 67.5GB
    (parted) quit

    dd if=/dev/sxb4 of=/dev/sxc1 bs=16M
```

As that will duplicate the UUID of the partition, in order to change the UUID of the new partition (make sure the partition is not mounted) run the following:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sxc1
tune2fs /dev/sxc1 -U random
```

if `sxb`is an old drive and you expect it to have read errors, use `ddrescue` instead.

<sub>**Note:** as `dd` is known as `d`isk `d`estroyer, and creating a partition table is dangerous, not putting the exact command in the above as some random idiot on the Internet might see this question and *copy-paste the codez* without understanding what it does...</sub>

Comment: Good to hear, I guess the only issue is I'm not sure how to create a partition with the exact same size? Is the 'size' the 'difference' between the start/end blocks of the partition?

Comment: Yes, correct.  And if you edit your question and provide the output of `parted --list` and leave another comment, I'll add that bit too.  **0:-)**

Comment: Urgh. Sorry: need it in bytes to be exact...  `sudo parted /dev/sdb unit B p` @ChrisStryczynski

Comment: I've just done it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Comment: Just a note that this seems to have duplicated the UUID of the partition - I'm not sure if this is any reason for concern though?

Comment: Not if you delete the old partition OR change the UUID on the new one: `uuidgen` and `tune2fs` for the latter. @ChrisStryczynski

Answer (score 1):

GParted can create and manipulate partitions. If you are using a Linux OS then you can also use GParted to achieve this goal entirely in a graphical user interface. In my case I had a few partitions on one drive and I wanted to back up just some of those partitions to another drive.

I attached drive 1 and drive 2 to my PC running Linux OS. Drive 2 had just one big partition on its whole disk. Using Gparted I resized that partition to free up space, enough to contain all the partitions from drive 1 that I wanted to back up. Then I created an "Extended" partition from the now unallocated space.

Then using GParted I selected drive 1 and clicked on a partition I wanted to copy... Partition Menu > Copy then switched to drive 2 then highlight the extended partition then Partition Menu > Paste. I repeated this for all the partitions I wanted to back up into the "Extended partition" on drive 2.